# PowerShell script : result issue

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to know why when I run my script the result shows me ";" between my arrays. I'm actually trying to compare two excel columns and display the difference. If a cell isn't in the first column but is in the second it display the column. How can I remove these ";" and get the difference between the columns? I've also tried with some files with one column and it works

result:

```
ComputerName;;;;;OtherComputerName
----------------------------------
uiojk;;;;;uih                     
hjbyu;;;;;ubyhi`
```

script:

```
#get the content of the column in the file
[string[]]$a = import-csv '.\test1.csv' | select -expand ComputerName
[string[]]$d = import-csv '.\test1.csv' | select -expand OtherComputerName

#display the cells which aren't in the $a list

$d |? {$a -notcontains $_}

#displays the columns of one file

[Array]$stores[2].ComputerName
[Array]$stores[2].OtherComputerName

$stores
```

Answer (score 2):

`Import-Csv` uses a comma as the default delimiter, if you want to use another character then you will need to use the `-Delimiter` option. Something like this:

```
$x = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $x.ComputerName -DifferenceObject $x.OtherComputerName
```

This code will generate a warning because not all your CSV columns have an header, but it will still work.